# Can't get user location after permission granted

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried get user location when button clicked using flutter `location` package

**Code**

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await location
        .hasPermission()
        .then((PermissionStatus status) async {
      if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
        await location.requestPermission().then(
          (PermissionStatus requestStatus) async {
            print("PERMISSION TAKEN");
            await location
                .getLocation()
                .then((LocationData userLocation) {
              print("LOCATION TAKEN 1");
              print(userLocation);
            });
          },
        );
      } else {
        await location
            .getLocation()
            .then((LocationData userLocation) {
          print("LOCATION TAKEN 2");
          print(userLocation);
        });
      }
    });
  },
  child: Icon(Icons.place, color: Colors.white),
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
),
```

When user clicked to button requested permission to location and in my code after permission granted work this part of my code

`print("PERMISSION TAKEN");`

But then not work this part of code

```
await location
    .getLocation()
    .then((LocationData userLocation) {
  print("LOCATION TAKEN 1");
  print(userLocation);
});
```

Comment: in what platform you are testing ios or android ? there is a currently a bug in iOS simulator in which you have to manually select a Location several in order for the Simulator to actually send data. Please keep that in mind when testing in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also get the location by following:---------

pubspec.yaml file under dependencies:----

```
dependencies:
 location: ^3.0.0
```

Android, add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

iOS, you have to add this permission in Info.plist  :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

**Warning:** there is a currently a bug in iOS simulator in which you have to manually select a Location several in order for the Simulator to actually send data. Please keep that in mind when testing in iOS simulator.

### main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter GPS',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: GetLocationPage(),
);
}
}

class GetLocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_GetLocationPageState createState() => _GetLocationPageState();
}

 class _GetLocationPageState extends State<GetLocationPage> {
  LocationData _currentLocation;
  Location _locationService = new Location();

  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();

_getLocation().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _currentLocation = value;
  });
});
 }

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        _currentLocation == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Text("Location:" +
                _currentLocation.latitude.toString() +
                " " +
                _currentLocation.longitude.toString()),
     

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
 }

  Future<LocationData> _getLocation() async {
   LocationData currentLocation;
try {
  currentLocation = await _locationService.getLocation();
} catch (e) {
  currentLocation = null;
}
return currentLocation;
 }
}
```

ss:---

[image]

In order to request location, you should always check manually Location Service status and Permission status. refer this https://pub.dev/packages/location

Comment: how did you get the location permission, since there is no code for permission request?

Comment: this line worked `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` without any code  for permission request @FaiiziiAwan

Comment: I need to get user location without clicking your `Get location` button. Whe I allow access location then your app status will be [loading](https://imgur.com/a/xWIW9TR) @Wini

Comment: @Wini updated version of answer can't get/display user location. You can see [here your code result](https://imgur.com/zdQSHbL)

Comment: @AndreasHunter i have implemented this code by using real device are you using the real device or emulator ?

Comment: I use in emulator @Wini

Comment: the screenshots which i have added is taken from real device can you also try real device

Comment: Now I will test on real device @Wini

Comment: @AndreasHunter try it with real one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225816/discussion-between-andreas-hunter-and-wini).

Answer (score 0):

i get current location as below , try to use like this

```
Future<LatLng> getUserLocation() async {
 LocationData currentLocation;

var location = new Location();
bool _serviceEnabled;
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
LocationData _locationData;

_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  }
}

_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.DENIED) {
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.GRANTED) {
  }
}

  // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
try {
  currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
  final lat = currentLocation.latitude;
  final lng = currentLocation.longitude;
  final coordinates = new Coordinates(lat, lng);
  var addresses =
      await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);

  var first = addresses.first;
  updateLocation(lat, lng, first.postalCode, first.locality,
      first.countryName, first.adminArea, first.addressLine);

  final center = LatLng(lat, lng);

  return center;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'PERMISSION_DENIED') {
    showToast("LOCATION PERMISSION DENIED",
        gravity: Toast.TOP, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
  currentLocation = null;
}
}
```

And don't forget to add this permission in Info.plist

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Comment: You call this function on button click or where you call this function? @manpreet singh pandher

Comment: in my case i call this method in initState method